# Access request.session from backend.get_user

Tags: django, authentication, session, request

first of all: this is *not* the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972267). The ModelBackend has no `request` member.

I want to access the session of the current user without access to the global request object or his/her session ID.

Why? I wrote my own authentication backend, extending `ModelBackend`. In that I have the function `get_user (self, user_id)`, that gets called with every request (this is done automatically by the Django auth middleware). Unfortunately, `get_user` doesn't have access to `request`, but nonetheless in my case I want to check with data in the session (Why again? Because I don't have a local database and get all data from a remote middleware. The session would be a comfortable way to do some kind of caching).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RemoteUserBackend` (from [`django.contrib.auth.backends`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L74)) uses special middleware, [`RemoteUserMiddleware`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L40), to access request data. Maybe you could do it this way, too.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an old thread but I am looking at the referenced code and I don't see where it is accessing the request data for the user I just authenticated.

Comment: @RonSmith I've updated the links a bit. The trick is that everything's done by `RemoteUserMiddleware.process_request` - it gets passed a `request` object (middleware.py#L40). It checks for presence of `Remote-User` HTTP header (L50) and if so passes that data to `RemoteUserBackend.authenticate` (L73) and saves the result in `request` (L77). In this case, only value of HTTP header is passeb, but the idea was that if you need session info in auth backend, you could preemptively stash it there from a middleware.

Comment: Do you mind update your answer with few lines of code as an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the tiny [ThreadLocalMiddleware](https://github.com/jedie/django-tools/blob/master/django_tools/middlewares/ThreadLocal.py). It makes the request object everywhere available.

```
from django_tools.middlewares import ThreadLocal

request = ThreadLocal.get_current_request()
# request.session <-- is now available
```

Do not forget to add the middleware into the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple of your settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django_tools.middlewares.ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a 'request' parameter to the `authenticate` function any time you call it:

```
def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
    ....
```

Comment: The question is about get_user function, no authenticate(..)

Comment: I still found the answer useful as I needed it during authenticate.