# Django - global name error when authenticate with multiple database

Tags: python, django

I have a basic app for login system, very very basic works ok, but now I'm trying to make it work with another database, at this it's not that easy as I thought. I was reading and I found I need a db router to make it work with my second database so I tried that.

Here's what I got :

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'db2':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'login.db'),
    }
}
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'myapp.middleware.CustomerMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.routers.MultiCustomerRouter']
```

**routers.py**

```
from middleware import my_local_global

class MultiCustomerRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return my_local_global.db2
```

**middleware.py**

```
from threading import local

my_local_global = local()

class CustomerMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        my_local_global.db2 = get_db2(request) # my database name is db2
```

I was following this [Django Authenticate Backend Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639830/django-authenticate-backend-multiple-databases) after I run `python manage.py runserver` I got this error:

> NameError at /
>
> global name 'get_db2' is not defined

How can I handle this to make it work as expected with my database `db2`?

**views.py**

```
def login_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    title = 'login'
    form = UserloginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        login(request,user)
        print(request.user.is_authenticated())
        return redirect('first_view')
    return render(request, "form.html",{"form":form,"title":title})
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to authenticate with `db2` not the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the question you link to is doing the same thing you want. If you just want to authenticate using a different database, you don't need thread locals or to set a variable on the request object - that question is about each customer using a different database (which will depend on the customer that's logged in, etc).

Your error is because you're calling a function `get_db2` that you haven't defined anywhere - you've clearly just copy/pasted most of that code from the other question without understanding what it does.

You may want to read the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) on database routers, which have an example that seems to do exactly what you want (you don't need middleware) - this is taken directly from the aforelinked page:

```
class AuthRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None
```

However, using different databases for different functionality is complex, so more than just the above would be required. Read the docs for more details.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir, worked as expected. well explained, better impossible :). Sorry for my noob question.