# Django url based multi database

Tags: django, database, django-rest-framework

I need to write users into two databases. I decided to send them to different url.
For example: `/register/dbone/` and `/register/dbsecond/` and then get `request.url` and separate them. 
But in Router two functions `db_for_read()` and `db_for_write()` do not know anything about `request` object and url.

How best to solve this? This is done because of the safe storage of data, so the initial storage of users in the first database is not possible.

P.S. Maybe there is some other way to separate users into two databases, not url but something else?

Comment: I find solution with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639830/django-authenticate-backend-multiple-databases

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a definitive answer, because I can't see all of your code, but the django docs show that `db_for_read()` and `db_for_write()` are actually called like:

`db_for_read(model, **hints)` and `db_for_write(model, **hints)` where `hints` are basically kwargs where, quoting django: `hints received by the database router can be used to decide which database should receive a given request.`

You are going to need to pass in any data from your request object (or whatever else decides the db) into these hints.